# Scrapy Amazon Pagination First Few Pages

Tags: scrapy

Currently for pagination in Amazon data scraper using Scrapy, I am using

```
next_page = response.xpath('//li[@class="a-last"]/a/@href').get()
        if next_page:
            next_page = 'https://www.amazon.com' + next_page
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page,callback=self.parse,headers=self.amazon_header,dont_filter=True)
```

Say if I want to only fetch data from the first 3 pages, How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to settings.py file and  you limit pagination like as follows:

```
CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT = 3
```

Alternative:
suppose,
url =[ 'https:// www.quote.toscrape/page=1 something']

Now make pagination this way in start_urls and exclude next
pagination

```
start_urls =[ '​https:// www.quote.toscrape/page='+str(x)+' something' for x in range(1,3)]
```

Comment: Fazlul, Thank you. I am Jupyter notebook. Where should I add this code?

Comment: set  "CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT = 3"  before spider class of your code

Comment: I've updated. This is working solution. I've made pagination this way more than one Amazon projects. Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much Fazlul. Appreciate this. Instead of 2 links, added one link and it worked great.

Comment: Glad to know that and thanks again for success.